# Adding admob to an iPhone app with cocos2d make the game crash...?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, admob

I'm working on a cocos2d game on iPhone. The game work perfectly.
Now I want to add an admob ad in the menu of my game. I can see the ad, but after few seconds (or minutes) of playing, the game crash (with no error message...)
Can you see where the problem is?

Menu.h

```
@interface Menu : CCColorLayer <AdMobDelegate> {  
    AdMobView *adMobAd;  
    NSTimer *refreshTimer;  
}
```

Menu.m

```
+(id) scene {...}  
-(id) init {...}  
-(void) dealloc {...}

- (void)didReceiveAd:(AdMobView *)adView {  
    adMobAd.frame = CGRectMake(-260, 432, 320, 48);  
    CGAffineTransform makeLandscape = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5f);  
    makeLandscape = CGAffineTransformTranslate(makeLandscape, -216, -134);  
    adMobAd.transform = makeLandscape;  
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:adMobAd];  
    [refreshTimer invalidate];  
    refreshTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:AD_REFRESH_PERIOD target:self selector:@selector(refreshAd:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];  
}  

- (UIViewController *)currentViewController {
    return nil;
}

- (void)onEnter {
    adMobAd = [AdMobView requestAdWithDelegate:self];
    [adMobAd retain];
    [super onEnter];
}

- (void)onExit {
    [adMobAd removeFromSuperview];
    [adMobAd release];
    [super onExit];
}

- (void)refreshAd:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [adMobAd requestFreshAd];
}

- (NSString *)publisherId {
    return @"zzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
}

- (UIColor *)adBackgroundColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.6 blue:1 alpha:1];
}

- (UIColor *)primaryTextColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
}

- (UIColor *)secondaryTextColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
}

- (BOOL)mayAskForLocation {
    return NO;
}
```

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you get rid of the `NSTimer` and use a `CCTimer` instead (and schedule it using `CCScheduler`).

You can do it with this code:

```
    refreshTimer = [CCTimer timerWithTarget:self
                                   selector:@selector(refreshAd:)
                                   interval:AD_REFRESH_PERIOD];
    [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleTimer:refreshTimer];
```